# Android - ListView doesn't scroll inside DialogFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-dialogfragment

I am starting developing for Android. I wanted t create my sort of modal alert (like UIAlertView in iOS). I considered using Activity which worked fine. It took some time for me to do it. But later, I found a better solution using DialogFragment. I changed my activity to a dialog fragment and modified all required parts with respect to a fragment. It works fine. Except that the ListView in my fragment doesn't scroll any more! What the problem could be?

Note: It was working already in the Activity solution. There is no scroll view.

Here is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/modal_list_outter_frame_margin_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/modal_list_outter_frame_margin_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/modal_list_outter_frame_margin_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/modal_list_outter_frame_margin_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/modal_list_outter_frame"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/modal_list_padding_bottom" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/modal_list_title_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/modal_list_title_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/modal_list_title_top_margin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="@integer/modal_list_title_number_of_lines"
        android:shadowColor="@color/modal_list_text_shadow_color"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="@integer/modal_list_title_shadow_offset_y"
        android:shadowRadius="@integer/modal_list_title_shadow_radius"
        android:text="@string/modal_list_title_small"
        android:textColor="@color/modal_list_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/modal_list_title_font_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/modal_list_inner_frame_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/modal_list_inner_frame_margin_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/modal_list_inner_frame_margin_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/modal_list_inner_frame_margin_top"
        android:background="@drawable/modal_list_inner_frame"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/modal_list_padding_bottom" >

        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/modal_list_list_view_margin_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/modal_list_list_view_margin_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/modal_list_list_view_margin_top"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" 
            android:listSelector="@color/modal_list_selector_color_selected"
            >

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update:** I found something really strange! It's like the fragment is transparent! If I tap anything in the fragment, it seems like I am tapping the buttons below it! Here is the code I am using to show the fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack("SingleSelectionCustomRowModalList");
modalList = ASModalList.newInstance(modalListStateForCustomRow) ;
modalList.show(ft, "SingleSelectionCustomRowModalList");
```

**Update 2:** It seems the problem is the DialogFragment is not modal. I am using this style:

```
int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE | DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME;
setStyle(style, R.style.ASModaListDialogStyle);
```

The used theme is:

```
<style name="ASModaListDialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/modal_list_background_view</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

I am using this theme to make the background of the dialog dimmed.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 1):

Old question without an answer that actually worked for me.
Hope it'll help someone.

The solution is to set the list height to 0dp, and add a weight field. And remove the inner `LinearLayout`. This way the outer `LinearLayout` can set the correct size to the list, and it will scroll.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat
    android:id="@+id/ev_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some code, otherwise it will be difficult to say what is wrong. For example the Layout XML or your DialogFragment Class.

Comment: Note: It's better for everyone to add something like this as a comment, rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It ends up with the dialog being non modal. Fixed it using:

```
int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL | DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME;
    setStyle(style, R.style.ASModaListDialogStyle);
```